# Do the Protheans make a significant appearance in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Given that the Protheans are the historical nemesis to the Reapers but were "all but wiped out", do they make an appearance in ME3 to help us win for once and all?

> I ask because we have the opportunity to recruit a Prothean into our crew according to some reviews I've read.  He will appear as downloadable contect, so will be optional to the story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Prothean you can recruit into your squad (The "From Ashes" DLC) has been in cryogenic stasis.

The Protheans as a powerful, space-faring race, are dead and gone, either killed or

> converted into Collectors by the Reapers.

Answer (score 0):

The DLC character is optional to the story, but offers some important lore.